# QField: change display label of entered features

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes, qfield, one-to-many

I'm experimenting with the QField app to visit trees regularly and monitor them over time. The tree inspections is a table related to a shapefile with the tree locations, so that every visit is associated with that particular tree and site. I have noticed that whenever I added a new feature to the list (tree inspections), they are all listed as '0'. I have attached a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image: new features listed with '0' as display name]

I can tap on the each entry to find out what variables were stored, but it is not very informative. Is there a way to display them as name of site and the date-time of visit, instead of the 0's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project at QGIS Desktop, you must open the **Layer Properties** and in **Display** change you Display Name. It can be an Expression based on 2 or more fields

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up the labels in your QGis project/desktop? You have the choice: no labels, simple labels, rule based labels... See printscreens. These settings are important for your QField mobile project.
As Nelson Silva said in a previous comment, it seems important for the feature list to have the display option filled in (see last printscreen).
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]